# Unable to run iOS 7.1.2 device in xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I've just updated my iPhone to iOS 7.1.2, and I can no longer run my apps through xcode 5.1.1. And I can't install apps with this iOS version too.

Comment: You need to download iOS SDK 7.1.2, check for updates in XCode.

Comment: @iphonic no you don't, Xcode will download the debug symbols from your device. Also there is no 7.1.2 SDK, there have never been any other then the 7.0 and 7.1

Comment: @rckoenes, do the xcode do it automatically? Because I can't install my app anymore when the iOS version is 7.1.2. Thanks.

Comment: Yes when you connect your device it will download the symbols automaticly. This might take some time, you can see this in the organizer. Also check if your device is have a green dot after its name.

Comment: @rckoenes, one more thing. After I archived my source code using iOS 7.1.2 device, can I install it to another 7.1.2 device? By the way, I'm distributing apps in-house. Thanks.

Comment: Should not be any problem. You can install any app signed with the InHouse profile on any device. The SDK version should not restrict this.

Comment: Please remember to mark the correct answer as the accepted answer to your question, in case any it solved your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue do the following:

1. Connect the device to your computer and open **iTunes**.
2. It will prompt you to *allow the computer to access the device*.
3. If you accept, the device should be properly recognized by **Xcode** too and selectable to run your app.

Still no clue why this happened in first place, after updating to iOS 7.1.2.